# anti virus deleted gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

I have a really big problem and don't know what to do. Earlier I got an anti virus and it prompted to clean my files and erase duplicate so I did. since I have installed `android studio` multiple times and have partially restarted windows I seen a big size of memory that I could get back. so when I deleted all the duplicate files I suppose there was some android studio files in there and not I am getting the error :

> "this project is using a unsupported version of gradle"

I have tried to uninstall and re install `android studio` 2 times and nothing works. when I click on the error which `android studio` usually always fix what ever issue it has it does nothing. and last I tried to make a new project and I get the same error so now I know it was not the project file I deleted but the `gradle` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using search try to find where is your gradle is located in your system, then copy the path.

**Then in your Android Studio:**
Go to file -> settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Gradle -> select 'Use local gradle distribution -> and select your gradle -> click apply -> OK

In case you do not find your gradle anywhere in your system, go here : https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and download your gradle file and take above steps.

Comment: one last question which one should i download , am using the current version of android studio. and also should i download older ones as well since i have a app am working on and i been working on it for a few months

Comment: You can try with latest one.

Comment: ok am sorry one last question .. the all have 3 version of each "all" "bin" "src" whitch one should i download

Comment: No need to say sorry. Try all.